# Pointers and getstring function

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to write a function to get a string from uart. Its for an embedded system so I don't want to use malloc.

The pointer that is passed to the getstring function seems to point to garbage after the gets_e_uart1() is called. I don't use pointers too often so I'm sure it is something really stupid and trivial that Im doing wrong.

```
int main()
    {   
        char *ptr  = 0;
        while(1)
        {

        gets_e_uart1(ptr, 100);
        puts_uart1(ptr);

    }
        return 0;
}*end main*/ 

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
//gets a string and echos it
//returns 0 if there is no error

char getstring_e_uart1(char *stringPtr_, const int SIZE_)

{

char buffer_[SIZE_];
stringPtr_ = buffer_;
int start_ = 0, end_ = SIZE_ - 1;
char errorflag = 0;

/*keep geting chars until newline char recieved*/
while((buffer_[start_++] = getchar_uart1())!= 0x0D)
{       
    putchar_uart1(buffer_[start_]);//echo it

    /*check for end of buffer 
     wraparound if neccesary*/
    if(start_ == end_)
    {
        start_ = 0;
        errorflag = 1;
    }
}
putchar_uart1('\n');
putchar_uart1('\r');

/*check for end of buffer 
 wraparound if neccesary*/
if(start_ == end_)
{
    buffer_[0] = '\0';
    errorflag = 1;
}
else
{
    buffer_[start_++] = '\0';
}
return errorflag;
}
```

**Update:**

I decided to go with approach of passing a pointer an array to the function. This works nicely, thanks to everyone for the informative answers.

**Updated Code:**

```
 //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 //argument 1 should be a pointer to an array, 
 //and the second argument should be the size of the array
 //gets a string and echos it
 //returns 0 if there is no error
char getstring_e_uart1(char *stringPtr_, const int SIZE_)
{

    char *startPtr_ = stringPtr_;
    char *endPtr_  = startPtr_ + (SIZE_ - 1);
    char errorflag = 0;

    /*keep geting chars until newline char recieved*/
    while((*stringPtr_ = getchar_uart1())!= 0x0D)
    {       
        putchar_uart1(*stringPtr_);//echo it
        stringPtr_++;

        /*check for end of buffer 
         wraparound if neccesary*/
        if(stringPtr_ == endPtr_)
        {
            stringPtr_ = startPtr_;
            errorflag = 1;
        }
    }
    putchar_uart1('\n');
    putchar_uart1('\r');

    /*check for end of buffer 
     wraparound if neccesary*/
    if(stringPtr_ == endPtr_)
    {
        stringPtr_ = startPtr_;
        *stringPtr_ = '\0';
        errorflag = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        *stringPtr_ = '\0';
    }
    return errorflag;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: `ptr` is pointing to garbage *before* gets_e_uart1() is called.

You need to pass a pointer to your pointer to `gets_e_uart1()`

**EDIT:** Except ... if you're trying to have `ptr` in `main()` point to the `buffer_` in your function ... you've got another problem. `buffer_` is on the stack and is out of scope as soon as the function returns. You would need to `malloc()` that memory in your function.

```
char getstring_e_uart1(char **stringPtr_, const int SIZE_)
{

    char *buffer_ = (char*) malloc(SIZE_ * sizeof(char));
    *stringPtr_ = buffer_;
```

*(Editing again because I wasn't paying attention to your main loop, sorry)*

Then you're going to have to free it after calling `puts_uart1(ptr)` which means you mallocing and freeing constantly in that loop. It seems you have a fixed size for that buffer, why not just create it in `main()` and pass it into both functions?

Comment: So if I create an array of  a certain size  in main and pass the array and the size of the array to the function, that should work right?(like I said I dont want to use malloc, so looking for other solutions)

Comment: Pass a pointer to it, but yes. Then you'd just operate directly on the buffer you created in main() rather than creating one in getstring_e_uart1()

Comment: Sorry thats what I meant as in a pointer to the first element. Im doing that now. I will post the results shortly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Brian's answer I think you also have a problem here:

```
char getstring_e_uart1(char *stringPtr_, const int SIZE_)   
{  
char buffer_[SIZE_]; 
stringPtr_ = buffer_;
```

after the function returns buffer is no longer valid but stringPtr_ would still point to it.  You could make buffer_ static or allocate it globally

Comment: Hmm I knew it was something stupid... I should of spotted that! Id rather not use global/static, Iv previously implemented a solution like that, I was looking for something a little more elegant. Can you suggest any thing else.
Regards, 
V

Comment: No, it doesn't. When the function returns, `ptr` in main is 0, exactly the same as when it started. You're right though, in that if he changes it to `**stringPtr_`, he'll have the problem where he's pointing to something on the stack that has gone out of scope.

Comment: You've got to allocate the memory somehow.  If it isn't a global array or a static array then you'll have to malloc it or allocate it in main and pass it into the function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to construct the buffer prior to invoking `getstring_e_uart1()`. The code as written will cause the buffer_ variable to be destroyed when the function exits.

I think you want something more like:

```
char buffer_[SIZE_];
while(1) {
  char* ptr = buffer_;
  gets_e_uart1(ptr, sizeof(buffer_));
  puts_uart1(ptr);
}
```

Note: I've done no verification regarding the reuse of the variable buffer_.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make the buffer static or global - you just have to have the *caller* allocate it.  The changes are trivial:

```
int main()
{   
    while(1)
    {
        char buffer[100] = { 0 };

        gets_e_uart1(buffer, sizeof buffer);
        puts_uart1(buffer);

    }
    return 0;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
//gets a string and echos it
//returns 0 if there is no error

char getstring_e_uart1(char *buffer_, const int SIZE_)
{
    int start_ = 0, end_ = SIZE_ - 1;
    char errorflag = 0;

    /* ... */
```